# GridLayout children are being clipped

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout for items in a `RecyclerView` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp" />
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
</GridLayout>
```

The problem is, the `TextView` and `WebView` extend outside the area I was expecting. Their right-hand-sides are cut off. The amount they're being cut off looks like it's the width of the first column.

What is causing this and how can I rectify?

Comment: cam you post a screenshot of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the items in the second column to have a width of 0dp and android:layout_gravity to fill horizontal. This should prevent them from clipping.

Comment: Thanks - that did indeed fix the problem. Android layout feels like voodoo to me.